# How do magic users learn memory modification and other advanced charms?

Tags: harry-potter

As far as I know, there's no mention of Memory Modification charms being taught at Hogwarts in class. Or any other non-school-level magic.

Also, as [was established on SFF before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8774/does-higher-education-exist-in-harry-potter), there's no university level education in wizarding world, aside from specialized trade training like Auror one.

So, how do people learn more advanced magic like Memory Modification charms (e.g. Lockhart who presumably did NOT go to Auror school), Occulumency or Legilemency?

Books?

Private tutoring?

I am looking for canon/JKR answer.

Comment: I would guess books, if only because Hermione seemed to use something similar on her parents, and Hermione seemed to learn a lot of extra magic from books.

Comment: I guess not everything is taught in school.

Comment: @Mooz - you'd make a very poor Hermione

Comment: Hahahah! That's true, but having gone through school and university and learned just about 15% of what I know; I'm now on the firm belief that **experience** is a much better teacher than books - sorry Hermione!

Comment: According to Pottermore, Lockhart hones his memory-modification skills after leaving school. None of his teachers seemed to realise he might be using such charms for his claimed exploits, so I don’t think there’s an “official” channel (e.g. tutoring). I would guess books (which would also be how Hermione learnt them). No idea about occlumency or legilimency.

Answer (score 1):

I think these advanced magic learnt by the students who studies **advanced Defence against the dark arts**.

> These were the books containing powerful Dark Magic never
>   taught at Hogwarts, and only read by older students studying advanced
>   Defense Against the Dark Arts.
>
> -*Harry potter and the sorcerer's stone (chapter twelve : THE MIRROR OF ERISED*)

They learn these type of advanced charms and not to mention , some of them teach these magic to other wizards also.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it comes from private tutoring (or books), as Snape had to teach Harry how to hide this thoughts.

Also it seems that some people are just natural Ocuulmens.

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Occlumency

Comment: The OP specifically asked for canon source, which excludes this wiki