# How do people like Madame Pomfrey learn magical healing?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Wizarding World, there are people like Madame Pomfrey and the staff of St. Mungo's who are devoted to the art of magical healing.

There doesn't seem to be a class at Hogwarts for it, and the brief amount that is taught in class (e.g. Slughorn's Potions class where they made an antidote) doesn't seem to be enough training for a career.

So how do they learn magical healing?

Comment: Additional schooling.  Interning at St. Mungos.  Med school in the real world doesn't happen in the teenage years either.

Comment: They... *experiment*.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually a duplicate, since this question is about how people learn magical healing and that question is about whether colleges exist. Yes, they seem to have similar answers, but the *questions* aren't duplicates.

Comment: @thunderforge - Actually you're right. It's a much closer dupe of [Where do Doctors/Healers get their training and research?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71440/where-do-doctors-healers-get-their-training-and-research/71447#71447)

Comment: Cheers @Rand al'Thor♦

Comment: @Valorum No problem, but could you not have reopened/reclosed it yourself with your shiny gold badge powers?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm reasonably sure that I can re-open it, but I can't then re-close it *for a different reason*.